# How can I check a message does it contain mention or not using discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I was making a new discord bot using discord.py and I wanted to interact with someone else using my bot. For example I will type "/mention @myfirend" and then my bot will reply with "Lexanspe mentioned @myfriend!". But if there is no mention, bot will reply with "You should mention someone!".

I didn't have any idea so I asked for copilot and it said if you want to make it with slash commands you should use different libraries but I have no idea for other libraries so I asked again and copilot started to giving stupid answers which is contains a lot errors so I want to ask you here.

Also I searched a lot but all the forums not about slash commands so I'm still don't know how to check a message.

Here's my code:

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.default(), activity=discord.Game(name='with arda'))

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("started")
    try:
        synced = await bot.tree.sync()
        print(f"Synced {len(synced)} commands(s)")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

@bot.tree.command(name = "gizli")
async def sa(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"as {interaction.user.mention}, slash komudu calisti ezzzzz", ephemeral=True)

@bot.tree.command(name = "ping")
@app_commands.describe(kimi = "say something")
async def say(interaction: discord.Interaction, kimi: str):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"{interaction.user.mention} mentioned {kimi}")

@bot.tree.command(name = "say")
@app_commands.describe(message = "say something")
async def say(interaction: discord.Interaction, message: str):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"{interaction.user.mention} said {message}")

bot.run("token")
```

I made something like that but as I said how can I check the message when someone use the "/ping"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just typehint `kimi` as a `discord.Member` object and if the argument is not provided the bot answers with "You should mention someone", otherwise the bot will mention the provided member.

```py
@bot.tree.command(name = "ping")
@app_commands.describe(kimi = "say something")
async def say(interaction: discord.Interaction, kimi: discord.Member=None):
    if kimi is None:
       await interaction.response.send_message("You should mention someone!")
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"{interaction.user.mention} mentioned {kimi.mention}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of getting the member object like @boez said, you check the incoming parameter to see if it has a valid user-id string. For example:

```
<@user-id>
```

The above is what a proper @(someone) should look like. We can use this to check if it's a user in the guild. This could also be useful if you want to exclude certain users from being pinged.

We can see this exact thing when we print the above with the following code:

```
@tree.command(name="say", guilds=[discord.Object(id=no)])
@app_commands.describe(user="Input valid user @")
async def say(interaction: discord.Interaction, user: str):
    print(user)  # print the user
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"{interaction.user.mention} mentioned {user}")
```

This returns:

```
<@497930397985013781>
```

If we edit the code to check if the ID is valid:

```py
@tree.command(name="say", guilds=[discord.Object(id=no)])
@app_commands.describe(user="Input valid user @")
async def say(interaction: discord.Interaction, user: str):
    user_id = re.sub("[^0-9]", "", user)  # remove all non characters
    if user_id.isdigit():  # check if it's a digit
        if interaction.guild.get_member(int(user_id)) is not None:  # String splice the mention to get the ID and pass it to get_member
            return await interaction.response.send_message(f"{interaction.user.mention} mentioned {user}")

    await interaction.response.send_message(f"Not a mention")
```

The above uses `re` but you can just import that with `import re`. If you don't want to use that, you could just splice the string instead.

Outputs:

[image: Outputs]

The top message is when I put a real @ for myself. The bottom message is when I put a non @ message.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to test it so I can't be sure it will run, but it should look like something like this :

```py
@bot.tree.command(name = "ping")
@app_commands.describe(kimi = "say something")
async def say(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    if interaction.message.mentions: # checks that the list of mentions is not empty
        toSend = f" mentionned {interaction.message.mentions[0]}"
    else:
        toSend = " did not manage to mention anyone"
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"{interaction.user.mention} {toSend}")
```

To check if the content of the message which triggered the slash command contains a mention, you need to retrieve the attribute Message of the Interaction. Then you can use the attribute Mentions of the Message to see if there is any valid mention in it.

[Interaction object Documentation](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/latest/api.html#nextcord.Interaction)

Comment: I can use slash code, there is no problem with it. When I use "/ping @myfriend" my bot replies with "@Lexanspe mentioned @myfriend" but how can I check does message contain any mention? Because you can also use as "/ping helloworld" and as you can see there is no mention but my bot will reply "@Lexanspe mentioned helloworld". I don't want it.

Comment: I added the code snippet to my answer.